# Checkbox issue ( selectable area offset )

Tags: javascript, css

I have a custom check box.

The issue I have is , on hover the actual image area ( that is clickable is out of whack ) if you try it out you will see,.. firebug element inspector is best.

Fiddle here : http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/YsbBM/1/ albeit sprite not displaying properly.

Actual demo here : http://sitehelp.com.au/demos/checkbox/

Js here:

```
function setCheckboxDisplay(el){
    var objWrap;
    objWrap = document.getElementById(el.id+"Wrap");
    if(el) {
        if(el.checked) objWrap.className = "styledCheckboxWrap wrapChecked";
        else  objWrap.className = "styledCheckboxWrap";
    }
}
```

CSS here:

```
    . styledCheckbox
   {
   line-height:20px;
    height:20px;
        width:20px;
    filter:alpha(opacity=0.0);
    opacity:0.0;
    outline:0
   }


. styledCheckboxWrap
{
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    background:url("/images/cbox.png") no-repeat top left;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
    margin:3px;
}
. wrapChecked{background-position: 0px -20px}
. checkboxLabel{
    float:left;
    cursor:pointer
}
```

html here:

```
<span id="checkboxWrap" class="styledCheckboxWrap"><input type="checkbox" id="checkbox" onclick="setCheckboxDisplay(this)" class="styledCheckbox" /></span>
```

Checkbox 1

The problem is the checkbox hover isnt spot on, for the width and height of the checkbox. So that you have to fumble around trying to get the exact position for clicking the damn thing.
Not sure what I have done wrong but its doing my head in fixing it. lol

Any suggestions please

Comment: thanks @minitech for tidying that up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your jsFiddle problem, change the drop-down that says "onDomReady" to "no wrap (head)" and it will work. As for the actual problem... do you mean that you can't click on the label to check the box, only the box? Because the checkbox works perfectly for me...

Comment: Updated the fiddle yep works perfect. But if you look at the site link I also posted with exact same code the issue is prevalent. When you bring the mouse over the icon ( checkbox ) it isnt clickable for the exact size of the checkbox, its kinda off whack. No bloody idea why. Click it and then try along the top edges to untick it etc. Its just out of alignment for some reason.

Comment: Really? Works fine in Google Chrome, which browser are you using?

Comment: < must be going mad lol ( perhaps was a cache issue ) it is working fine now. Testing in ie chrome and ff . Sorry guys, I seem to be a bit of a "wally" today Will vote you guys for responding and testing, regards :)